# The equivalent of \localleftbox and \localrightbox in XeTeX

Tags: xetex

In Omega (and Aleph) there was a pair of very useful commands called `\localleftbox` and `\localrightbox`, which would put the typeset contents of their unique argument at the left and at the right of every TeX line in the DVI file. This is very useful to put metadata to every DVI line (for example the number of the paragraph, the type of the paragraph, etc.) and to know exactly where the line starts and ends.

Here is an example (compiled with Aleph):

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{A Test Document}
\author{Me}
\usepackage{graphics,color}
\begin{document}
\localleftbox{\textcolor{red}{BLA}}
\localrightbox{\textcolor{red}{BLI}}
\maketitle
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula 
eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient 
montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
\localleftbox{}\localrightbox{}pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, 
justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:[image]

Notice in the example that when I call the commands inside the text before pellentesque, they immediately affect the paragraph (i.e., they act on the line level and not on the paragraph level).

These commands do not exist in XeTeX. I know this is probably only wishful thinking, but **do you know of any other way of achieving the same result?** All I need is to add a special in the XDV file at the begin and at the end of every line, together with some metadata about the line. So that I can parse the XDV file and know exactly where a line starts and what kind of line it is.

Comment: XeTeX is based on e-TeX not Omega, so I think 'they do not exist' is the answer

Comment: I guess you know, but they are in luatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes but does luatex produce a DVI or XDV file?

Comment: well dvilualatex makes a dvi file, but if you use opentype fonts there are not many dvi drivers that can cope (not compatible with xetex's xdv) however there was one driver announced last year I think I'll report back.

Comment: https://github.com/vtex-soft/texlive.xdvipsk (not tried this!)

Comment: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-2/tb119tolusis.pdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2):

xetex does not have any feature close to this.

luatex does inherit them (from your omega system). If you need DVI processing you can use dviluatex.  The only problem then is if you use OpenType fonts the DVI format is extended in a different way than xetex's extensions so the dvi file is not processable by any dvi driver in the standard distributions.

There is however an experimental extension of dvips that was documented in tugboat that supports dviluatex, although I have not tried it.

Source:

https://github.com/vtex-soft/texlive.xdvipsk

TUGBoat article:

https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-2/tb119tolusis.pdf